# Leaflet Markers All Have Same Value

Tags: javascript, closures, leaflet

I'm working in Leaflet with Mapbox and Javascript. I know that the root of my problem is with javascript closure inside loops. I've looked at all the other examples and can't seem to find one similar to mine.

I have a for loop looping through the points i'm adding but they all end up being the same value.

This is adding the leaflet marker with what should be the features attached attributes

```js
marker.bindPopup(<button class = "trigger" onclick = buttonClick(geojsonFeature) </button> )
```

This is the onclick function which when called should show the count which happened at that point but it shows the last count from the loop

```js
function buttonClick(object){
    alert(object.properties.Count)
}
```

I've tried something similar to this:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    function clickHandler(num) {
        $("#div" + i).click(
            function() {
                alert(num)
            }
        )
    }
    clickHandler(i);
```

but with no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

By the time button is clicked, geojsonFeature is not what you think it is ...

So you have to store it somewhere and provide a way to retrieve it when button is clicked.

Something like ...

```
//your creation loop
jsonString = JSON.stringify(geojsonFeature); 

marker.bindPopup(<button class = "trigger" data-json = jsonString onclick = buttonClick(this) </button> )
// Note the this operator that will give context when the button is clicked
// end of your creation loop

function buttonClick(object){
    // retrieve button attribute called data-json and make it an object
    feature = JSON.parse(object.getAttribute("data-json"));
    alert(feature.properties.Count)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it didn't work unfortunately. Why did you stringify the object before you passed it?

Comment: html attributes can only hold strings. Can you share what you are trying (on jsfiddle for example) to see where it goes wrong ?

Comment: I sort of ended up figuring it out. I created a list outside of the loop which held each geojsonFeature I then called on indexes inside of that list so it 'remembered' the value. Thanks for all your help and interest!